# Drawing a circle in Java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I want to draw a circle which has the follow properties:

- Center is the point where the user first clicks the mouse on the window
- Radius should be the length of the distance between when the mouse is first clicked and when it's released (i.e. mouse dragging).

Here's what I have so far but it's not doing what I need it to do:

```
package assignment;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawCircle extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    private int centerX;
    private int centerY;
    private int endPtX;
    private int endPtY;
    private double radius;
    private double w;
    private double h;
    private CirclePanel circPanel;

    /** constructor **/
    public DrawCircle() 
    {
        this.setTitle("Click to Draw Circle");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.circPanel = new CirclePanel();
        this.circPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        this.add(this.circPanel);
        pack();
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        centerX = e.getX();
        centerY = e.getY();
        circPanel.set(centerX, centerY, radius, radius);
        repaint();
        pack();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        endPtX = e.getX();
        endPtY = e.getY();

        radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endPtX - centerX, 2) + Math.pow(endPtY - centerY, 2));
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}



    //circle panel
    private class CirclePanel extends JComponent
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int w;
        private int h;

        public void set(int x, int y, double width, double height)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            w = (int) width;
            h = (int) height;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawOval(x, y, w, h);
        }
    }

    //main method
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        new DrawCircle();
    }
}
```

Comment: The overall idea is to draw a circle on a JPanel, whose radius is determined by user dragging a pressed mouse and then releasing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing the

```
circPanel.set(centerX, centerY, radius, radius);
repaint();
pack();
```

in the wrong place you shouldn't draw the circle until the user lets go of the mouse because that's when the radius is set and before that the radius is 0 so there is nothing drawn. Try moving that to the `mouseReleased` method.

Comment: That did the trick, but the center of the circle is not located at the coordinates of the first mouse click. How did I fix this?

Comment: The `drawOval` method doesn't take in the center of the oval it takes in the upper left hand coordinates (it also takes in width and height not radius) you're going to have to modify the value of x,y, and radius to the values expected by `drawOval`

Comment: I just posted a question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219349/java-is-there-any-easy-way-to-draw-a-circle-onto-a-jpanel I don't know how to account for this

Comment: I don't think you need a new question. All you need to do is take your center point and radius and do the math.