# Draw a circle using 2 mouse clicks

Tags: java, swing

I need to draw a simple circle by using mouse clicks 
First click will be the center
Second will be the radius and the circle would be draw by the 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is how to ask this question correctly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836440/how-to-draw-circle-on-jpanel-java-2d

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Is there any easy way to draw a circle onto a JPanel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219349/java-is-there-any-easy-way-to-draw-a-circle-onto-a-jpanel)

Comment: Just provide me with a billing address to send my invoice to ... put a bit more effort in your question and perhaps it will remain open

Comment: I need new system for my eshop. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question! The code below is a self contained example (I'm using dragging to define the radius):

[image: screenshot]

### Code that produces screenshot above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        Point p; int r; 
        {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    p = e.getPoint(); r = 0; repaint();
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    r = (int) Math.round(e.getPoint().distance(p));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    r = (int) Math.round(e.getPoint().distance(p));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(p != null) g.drawOval(p.x - r, p.y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r); 
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

### Example using 2 clicks:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        Point p1, p2;
        {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (p1 == null || p2 != null) { 
                        p1 = e.getPoint();
                        p2 = null;
                    } else {
                        p2 = e.getPoint();
                    } 
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(p1 != null && p2 != null) {
                int r = (int) Math.round(p1.distance(p2));
                g.drawOval(p1.x - r, p1.y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);
            }
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is an option to do this by 2 divided clicks ?

Comment: Sure! Added example using two clicks (but I think this is harder to see the size of the circle when not having any "dragging" involved)

Comment: Thanks dacwe ! you help me in a big project